# Cookies not shared accros the controller in spring MVC

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, cookies

In my `spring application`, post login, I'm setting some information in the `response.addCookie(cookie)` and I'm able to view the `cookie name and value` in the browser. Through the javascript I'm able to access the `cookie`.

When I'm navigating to another `controller`, those `cookies` are not even available in the `filter`, `interceptor` and in the `controller` as well.

I've tried to create a form dynamically on click of anchor tag and set the hidden value field with the cookie value and have received the details as getParameter and it works fine. But, since its `get` method, my URL displays the parameters in the URL. If I change the method to `post`, then it'll be pain area in the `controller` side `redirection` to another `controller`(since the redirection happens as `get` method).

Could you please sort out this issue?

Can't we pass the cookie across the controller without setting it up explicitly?

Comment: Show some code??

Answer (score 0):

You would not be able to get those cookies if you are navigating to the controller directly( maybe using `RequestDispatcher`). You need to ask your browser to do the work for you.

You should use `response.sendRedirect("/your-controller-path")` in order to retrieve the cookies from your request.

Comment: If I maintain some information in the page cookie and i need it in the each controller during the navigation, how to get it? For example, I have encrypted cookie in my browser, that cookie is required to get some data from db and assign the value to the next model. How to get the data then?

Comment: I would suggest you re-think. Do you really want cookies for this??

Comment: I'm making it as stateless. Dont want to maintain any session. In this case, how do I know who is sending request? I've my-own enc algorithm to decrypt and validate whether the request is coming from authenticated user or not. in this case i need cookie only right? I'm maintaining user info like display name, dp image path, user role, unique dynamic key in all the cookie. so, i thought it would be tough to decrypt from the attackers.

Comment: Statelessness and authentication are two different things. If you have implemented Any auth mechanism.(example you use JWT tokens) Then use the token to identify the request and sender

Comment: Using a cookie to share info across all controllers won't be a good choice for this specific use case

Comment: How to send the JWT token to controller then?

Comment: With request headers

Comment: I'm navigating a form page through the controller. On page loading itself, I would require some info updated in the Model. Model attribute I'm setting it which has been taken from DB. To query the DB i need token or cookie anything is fine. When we click on a link, it will be a simple get method only right? How to set request header on an anchor link click? will it be supported in IE7 also if we customize the actual request?